# MSAL for Angular Preview angular webpack AOT compilation not including resourceMap

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am creating my protectedResourceMap and I am passing the const to the @NgModule as stated in the documentation.

```js
export const  protectedResourceMap: Map<string, Array<string>> = new Map<string, Array<string>>();

protectedResourceMap.set("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]);
protectedResourceMap.set("https://buildtodoservice.azurewebsites.net/api/todolist", ["api://a88bb933-319c-41b5-9f04-eff36d985612/access_as_user"]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [ MsalModule.forRoot({
                  clientID: Your client ID,
                  protectedResourceMap : protectedResourceMap
                })]
           })
```

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md

But when I run **ng build with --prod**  (with AOT on by the default), then the AOT compiler try to optimize the code, it adds all the other parameters of MSalConfig, but it doen not add my resourceMAP (as show in the image bellow).

If I turn off buildOptimizer and AOT in the Angular.Json file, it works fine.

Is that a bug? any ideas on how to workaround that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted an issue in the MSAL github project and they answered a fix for that will be released in the new version.
BTW this issues is with the version 0.2.2 of MSAL wrapper for Angular.

You can check more information about that here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/407